# Q:How to force destroy a viewcontroller in iOS？

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, controller, presentmodalviewcontroller

Is it possible to recycle/force destroy a `UIViewController` in iOS ?

I am using this [github project](https://github.com/CoderJackyHuang/HYBControllerTransitions) to get a custom `UIViewControllerTransition`:

Here is the flow of the program:

- `vc1` presents to a `nav` to which the `rootVc` is `vc2`
- In `vc2` there is a `UIButton`. When clicked, `vc2`'s `NavigatioCcontroller` will dismiss.

But the issue is that `vc2` is not recycled by the OS, so when I progress to `vc1`, then present to `nav` (which `rootVc` is `vc2`), `vc2` does not call the `viewDidLoad` method.

Not sure where the problem lies. Is there a way so that when I click `vc2`'s `UIButton`, force destroy the `nav` and `vc2`? This way, when I re-present to `nav`, `vc2`'s `viewDidload` will be called again.

**Code**:

in `vc1`:

```
LMLQQSearchSelectViewController *search_vc = [[LMLQQSearchSelectViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LMLQQSearchSelectViewController" bundle:nil];
search_vc.fromController = @"KnowledgeViewController";
search_vc.pre_type = @"ENCYCLOPEDIACOL";
LMLQQSearchNavController *nav = [[LMLQQSearchNavController alloc] initWithRootViewController:search_vc];
nav.navigationBarHidden = YES;


__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

_search_header.block = ^(){

    weakSelf.transition = [[HYBEaseInOutTransition alloc] initWithPresented:^(UIViewController *presented, UIViewController *presenting, UIViewController *source, HYBBaseTransition *transition) {
        HYBEaseInOutTransition *modal = (HYBEaseInOutTransition *)transition;

        // If you don't specify, it will use default value
        // Default is NO, if set to YES, it will use spring animation.
        modal.animatedWithSpring = NO;
    } dismissed:^(UIViewController *dismissed, HYBBaseTransition *transition) {
        // do nothing
    }];

    nav.transitioningDelegate = weakSelf.transition;
    [weakSelf presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:NULL];

};
```

Answer (score 0):

When `nav` is dismissed, you must be hanging onto a reference to it so that you can redisplay it later. And because `nav` is holding a reference to `vc2`, you get the same instance back again when you redisplay `nav`.

You have two options. One, you could release your reference to `nav` after it is dismissed, which will then release `vc2` as well. Two, you could move the code you want to run every time `vc2` appears from `viewDidLoad` into `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: I have think of the `option 2`, it will cause some trouble in my project, I will take a test in option 1, do you mean in the method:`[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
       // reset the root vc? 
    }];`